# How much programming is practiced in Theoretical Computer Science jobs?

Tags: career

I am an undergraduate student studying Information Technology. I like both math and CS, so I am considering to go into either "Computer Science and Math" or "Theoretical Computer Science" for my postgraduate study. Some of the fields I'm interested are: combinatorial and computational complexity.

I heard that the only career option in Theoretical CS is to become a researcher - and from where I come from, research are not strongly supported and encouraged (especially in CS), so researcher is not just a common career here.

But what I concern the most is people tell me that there are little programming practice in TCS, while I enjoy programming.

1. Is that true? Of all the research categories in TCS, which ones require more programming practices and what programming is used for there?
2. I have never worked theoretical math & rigorous math analysis e.g.: proving theory etc, though I'm quite sure I can master it if I learn it. How much will it affect me if I study TCS?

Your answer will be a great help for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: TCS uses as much maths as you have available: the more, the better!  If you don't have a strong maths background or experience proving theorems, then you will not like TCS.  Some top results in TCS have a programming component (for instance, Ryan Williams' separation of ACC$^0$ and NEXP), but programming is a tool and not the main focus in TCS, even in programming languages.  There are programming jobs supporting TCS researchers, especially in PL, but they still require a strong maths background.  If you want to explore a TCS career, try some hard maths or logic courses and reassess.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon what is PL?

Comment: @Turbo: programming languages

Comment: Hi Luke, I think that for both questions the answer can vary.  My recommendation for you would be to try and get advice from some people (students/professors/professionals) in TCS at your university or in your local area.  It's often not easy so I wish you luck and have a great day.

Comment: There are lots of people who get degrees in theoretical computer science and then go on to programming jobs in industry, at least in the U.S. I don't know whether industry has some unwarranted prejudice against hiring people with theory degrees where you come from; they certainly will understand the algorithms they are implementing much better than the average programmer.